# Acid reflux (GERD) in a dog with chronic kidney disease

Tags: dogs, health

My 12.5 yo Labrador retriever has chronic kidney disease (early stage 3, non-proteinuric) and as a result, or possibly coincidentally, has what is probably acid reflux. He groans when he lays down, and periodically while he is laying down. More than half of the groans are followed by licking his lips and swallowing. I think it is affecting his sleep, which is no help for his health in general. He will also groan a little when he stretches. He has osteoarthritis in his back, with bridging between 3 pairs of vertibrae, but has no mobility issues.

At the suggestion of his vet, I have tried famotidine 10 mg 2x/day. I have been splitting his daily ration of food into 4 meals per day. Two days ago, I started giving him a commercial alginate gel preparation after meals and before bed. At the suggestion of his vet, on two occaisions in the past (20 mg/day for 10 days, then weeks later 5 mg/day for 4 days), I have given him omeprazole, which seemed to help some, but carries greater risk of kidney injury than does famotidine and, though possibly a coincidence, both occaisions were followed by declines in his kidney function (high BUN following the first occaision, decreased USG following the second), making me leary of trying it again.

Nothing tried so far really seems to have helped much. I have considered trying different dog foods, and he is currently on his second brand of commercial kidney support food. The vet has suggesting doing an upper endoscopy, but another vet at the same prectice warned against sedation because of the kidney disease. Calcium carbonate antacids are out because of the risk of hypercalcemia.

Has anyone found anything helpful for dogs with GERD?

Comment: It may not be GERD. Kidney disease is often accompanied by nausea. Ask your vet about proper diagnosis and treatment.

Comment: GERD is a far more serious diagnosis than "simple" acid reflux. Where does this diagnosis come from? Groaning while laying down is a common expression of content in dogs and lip licking can mean a great number of things. Has any vet diagnosed acid reflux in your dog or did you just assume? As with any kind of medication, it can cause harm if the recipient isn't actually ill, so I wouldn't treat a dog (especially one with kidney disease) without a reliable diagnosis.

Comment: I was wondering what you ended up doing? my dog also has Kidney disease and reflux. I have not tried the commercial food He is currently on Dr Martys small breed and famotidine also. I don't know if the food not being for kidney disease is making his have all this reflux. I have read so many things about the foods. I am confused wondering if giving him chicken and rice would help